cudaの使用率が低い
cudaの使用率が24%と割と低いです。
cuda自体は認識しているのですが実際にはあまりcudaの使用率が改善しませんどうしたらいいでしょうか?cpuの使用率も高くありません。どうしたら改善するのでしょうか
環境
windows11
gpu:RTX 4070 ti super 16GB
cpu:AMD Ryzen 5 3600XT 6-Core Processor
nvidia-smi
Thu Oct 24 20:33:07 2024
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 565.90                 Driver Version: 565.90         CUDA Version: 12.7     |
|-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                  Driver-Model | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                        |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+========================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070 ...  WDDM  |   00000000:2B:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 33%   59C    P0             40W /  285W |    1228MiB /  16376MiB |      1%      Default |
|                                         |                        |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                              |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                              GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                               Usage      |
|=========================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1008    C+G   ...Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2868    C+G   ...on\130.0.2849.52\msedgewebview2.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      5452    C+G   C:\Windows\explorer.exe                     N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      8728    C+G   ...2txyewy\StartMenuExperienceHost.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     10872    C+G   ...nt.CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy\SearchHost.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     11576    C+G   ...oogle\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     12300    C+G   ...B\system_tray\lghub_system_tray.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     12332    C+G   ...on\130.0.2849.52\msedgewebview2.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     13664    C+G   ...oogle\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     13912    C+G   ...5n1h2txyewy\ShellExperienceHost.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     17052    C+G   C:\Windows\System32\ShellHost.exe           N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     19012    C+G   ...CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy\TextInputHost.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     22192    C+G   ...__8wekyb3d8bbwe\WindowsTerminal.exe      N/A      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

コード
import os
import torch
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
from peft import AutoPeftModelForCausalLM
import time
import random
import Loadquestion
import AgTranslate
from huggingface_hub import login


# Hugging Faceのトークンを設定

os.environ["HF_TOKEN"] = hf_token
login(hf_token)


# モデルの設定
adpt_path = "./model/BadMargeModel"
repo_id = "elyza/Llama-3-ELYZA-JP-8B"


try:
    # モデルの読み込み
    model = AutoPeftModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
        pretrained_model_name_or_path=adpt_path,
        local_files_only=True,
        device_map="auto",  # 自動的にデバイスを割り当て
        torch_dtype=torch.float16,
        load_in_4bit=True  # 4bit量子化
    )
    print("Success-Load-Model")
except EOFError:
    print("failure-Model-Load")

try:
    # トークナイザーの読み込み
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(pretrained_model_name_or_path=repo_id)
    if tokenizer.pad_token is None:
        tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
    tokenizer.padding_side = "right"
    print("Success-Load-Tokenizer")

except EOFError:
    print("failure-Load-Tokenizer")


print("[Success]-Tokenizer-Model-Load")


# 質問の設定
QuestionCSVpath = "seePointANDtheme.csv"
seePoints, themes = Loadquestion.LoadQuestion(QuestionCSVpath)
conversation_history = []

NowTestMode=True



theme = input("テーマ:")

whatCountUse = 5

answer_temp = r""
answerS = []
for i in range(whatCountUse):
    answerS.append(r"")

SystemPrompt_start = "あなたは問題点を指摘するのが得意なアドバイザーです。今回は箇条書きで回答アドバイスしてください"
SystemPrompt = SystemPrompt_start
conversation_history.append({"role": "user", "content": SystemPrompt})

def promptCustmise(theme,question):
    theme_t = AgTranslate.do_translate(theme)
    question_t = AgTranslate(question)
    

#テストで必要な要素
#SystemPromptの変更[
#Promptの表示

def reset():
    global theme
    conversation_history = []
    conversation_history.append({"role": "user", "content": SystemPrompt_start})
    theme = input("テーマ:")
    print("\n\n",SystemPrompt_start,"\n\n")

def changeSystemPrompt():
    SystemPrompt = input("SystemPromptを入力してください")
    conversation_history[0] = {"role": "user", "content": SystemPrompt}

def customization():
    global theme
    changeSystemPrompt()
    theme = input("テーマ:")

# 回答スタート
while True:
    # ランダムに質問を生成
    user_input = Loadquestion.makeQuestion(seePoints[random.randint(0, len(seePoints) - 1)], theme)    

    line_Q=""
    for i in range(len(user_input)):
        line_Q += "-"
    print(line_Q)
    print("Q:",user_input)
    print(line_Q)

    start_time = time.time()
    conversation_history.append({"role": "user", "content": user_input})

    # プロンプトの生成
    prompt = tokenizer.apply_chat_template(
        conversation=conversation_history,
        tokenize=False,
        add_generation_prompt=True
    )

    # 入力データの生成
    model_inputs = tokenizer([prompt], return_tensors="pt", padding=True).to("cuda")

    with torch.cuda.amp.autocast():  # 混合精度を使用してメモリを節約
        generated_ids = model.generate(
            model_inputs.input_ids,
            attention_mask=model_inputs.attention_mask,
            max_new_tokens=300
        )

    # 生成された回答を取得
    generated_ids = [
        output_ids[len(input_ids):] for input_ids, output_ids in zip(model_inputs.input_ids, generated_ids)
    ]

    # トークンIDを文字列に変換
    response = tokenizer.batch_decode(generated_ids, skip_special_tokens=True)[0]
    # answer_temp = PromptTranslate.translate_Japanese(response)
    # answer_temp = Argostranslate.translate("en","ja",response)
    # answer_temp = AgTranslate.do_translate(response,"en","ja")
    answer_temp = response

    print("回答:", answer_temp)
    # 会話履歴に回答を追加
    conversation_history.append({"role": "assistant", "content": response})

    end_time = time.time()
    print("実行時間: {:.2f}秒".format(end_time - start_time))

    # メモリキャッシュの解放
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()

    whatCountUse -= 1
    # answerS[whatCountUse] = answer_temp
    if whatCountUse <= 0:
        #nextTest
        if NowTestMode:
            try:
                whatCountUse = int(input("何回出力する?半角数字:"))
            except ValueError:
                break

            print("+changeSP-SystemPromptを変更する\n")
            print("+reset-SystemPromptをリセットして、themeを変更する\n")
            print("最初のsystemPrompt:",SystemPrompt_start)
            print("+custom-SytemPrompt/themeを変更\n")
            
            user_input = input("オプションを入力してください:")
            
            if user_input == "changeSP":
                changeSystemPrompt()
                continue
            if user_input == "reset":
                reset()
                continue
            if user_input == "custom":
                customization()
            else:
                break
        else:
            break

print("回答を終了させていただきました")


同じことをやっている人からすれば自明なのかもしれませんが、何を基準としたり比べたりしているのかの情報を追記した方が良いと思われます。関連する度合いは不明ですがこんな記事あたりでしょうか？ 【WSL2】コンテナを使ってLlama 3.1をローカルで動かしてみる, Llama3，Phi-3などの対話型人工知能（大規模言語モデル）をパソコンで動かす, Llama3の論文を読む
